# org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: Error resolving template "xxxx-page", template might not exist or might not be accessible

Tags: java, xml, maven, spring-boot

I am trying to add thymeleaf configuration to my pom.xml and I am getting this error

```
org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: Error resolving template "xxxx-page", template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers
```

this is a snippet from my pom.xml file

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
```

Please what could be wrong?

Comment: have you verified your templates path are they configured correctly for your thymeleaf template resolvers

Comment: I am using jsp placed in my web-inf folder

Comment: Was thinking that thymeleaf works only with .html files

Comment: you are correct

Comment: As I am using jsp on commenting out thymeleaf in pom.xml everything works perffectly